# Grails Compile Event

Tags: events, grails, compilation

When running under `grails run-app` is there a way to run a script if any file(s) are recompiling?

I want to run a custom script when any file has been changed and is being recompiled. The `eventCompileStart` only runs when building a war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running grails 1.3.7.  I created an _Events.groovy file in grails-app/scripts.  It contains the following:

```
eventCompileStart = { kind ->
  println "Triggered ${kind}"
}
```

The first time I did a grails run-app I got the output.  I then left the application running, and created a new Domain.  Again, I got the output.  It does not only execute on grails war.

Comment: Don't you hate those? :)  Glad it was simple.